# Css indent parent/child

Tags: html, css

I have a problem: I need to make indent from top of the form to "Sign up". But when i declare

```
padding-top: 75px;
```

at `p.header` this attribute is applied to the whole form.
By the way this works properly at snippet here.

```css
.main__form{
    height: 729px;
    width: 516px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 20px rgba(40, 40, 40, 0.2);
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.form__wraper{
    max-width: 420px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.input__section{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

input{
    border: 1px solid #EDEEF0;
    border-radius: 2px;
    width: 420px;
    height: 56px;
    margin-bottom: 32px;
}

p.header{
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 32px;
    line-height: 40px;
    letter-spacing: 0.01em;
    color: #282828;
    padding-top: 76px;
    margin-bottom: 14px;
}
```

```html
<form class="main__form">
            <div class="form__wraper">
                    <p class="header">               
                      Sign up
                    </p>
                    <div class="input__section">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Name*">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="E-mail*">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Password*">
                    </div>
            </div> 
</form>
```

Comment: css working perfectly what you mean ----applied to whole form

Comment: Do you mean the bottom has too much space? If so, that is caused by the height you've set as 729px. Change that to, example 429px and it should be better.

Comment: May be if you want and indent at the top you might not use `padding-top: 75px;` just use
`margin-top` because `padding` increase the space inside while `margin` just leave space between items so, I recommend you to use `margin-top` instead `padding-top` if I heard your problem clearly cause if you use `padding-top` of course it extract the inner top space of `p.header` which also affect the form too